# How to remove this latch handle (no screws, no slot)

Tags: lock

I am having difficulty removing this latch handle. I've removed the face plate but I'm unsure of next steps.

For context, the handle isn't working.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: All the screws are out of the rosettes?

Comment: What does the other side look like?

Comment: In that last pic it looks like there's still some sort of screw head, rivet, something in that hole that's closest to us. It's possible that's still holding it on to the door. Again, views from the other side may tell the rest of the story.

Comment: There's likely a set screw or perhaps a small spring loaded prong holding the handle on.  If the rosette wasn't oriented right, it could be underneath the lip of the rosette.